# add_filter('the_content', 'method') does not trigger my custom method

Tags: filters, content

I'm using the parse_request hook to trigger the the_content filter when you're at `/sportivity-roster` in the url. When I do a var_dump in the if statement where I check the constant it's value, it works, but for some not knowing reason it is not reaching my method which should get triggered in the the_content hook.

```
add_action('parse_request', 'sportivity_roster_custom_url_handler');
function sportivity_roster_custom_url_handler() {
    global $wp;
    $path = $wp->request;
    if($path === sup::ROSTER_URL) { 
        add_filter('the_content', 'generateView', 1);
    }
}

function generateView($content){
    $weeks = sportivity_roster_get_lessons(array_values(Location::loadAll())[0]->getSportivityApi());
    $index = 0;
    $contents = array();
    foreach($weeks as $week => $lessons) {
        foreach($lessons as $locationId => $lessonsForWeek) {
            $weekSelector = sprintf('.location.%s .week_%s', $locationId, $index);
            $content = sportivity_roster_makeWeek($lessonsForWeek, array(), $weekSelector);
            $contents[$weekSelector] = $content;
            $index++;
        }
    }

    $data = array(
        'lessons' => $weeks,
        'contents' => $contents,
        'lessons_bookable' => false,
    );
    return sup::includeView('roster', $data);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `if($path === sup::ROSTER_URL) { ` is succesful? How have you verified this? Have you checked your PHP error log for warnings that could have caused this? Have you tried replacing the code in your filter with `return "it works";`? or added a `wp_die( 'adding filter' )` in `sportivity_roster_custom_url_handler`? Does the page at that URL call `the_content()`?

Comment: @TomJNowell inside the if statement I did a var_dump which was successful. Then I tried the return it works, but no success. the wp_die does not work eitherand the custom url handler should return a php template instead

Comment: what is in the custom PHP template? How is the content being displayed? Note that while `the_content` calls the filter, grabbing the raw post content via `get_the_content` or `$post->post_content` does not